# Find the value of the remainder

Tags: number-theory

I need to find the remainder b, that is a common remainder when the numbers $551$, $613$ and $768$ are divided by $a>1$. It can be done by system of equations?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If the remainders are the same, then $a$ must divide $613-551$ and $768-613$.

**Added:** The differences are $62$ and $155$. So if the three numbers have a common remainder on division by $a$, then $a$ must divide both $62$ and $155$. The only common divisors of these two numbers are $a=1$ (not allowed) and $a=31$.

To find $b$, find the remainder when any of our numbers is divided by $31$.

Comment: Gracias Nicolas voy a probar con eso

Comment: I still can't figure it out.

Comment: I will add some material.